# How to add new methods to a class after importing it?

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

How can we add methods to a class that we imported from another code file in python?

Comment: In Python, you can dynamically add methods to classes directly:" `MyClass.some_method = some_method`. Or perhaps, as the answers here suggest and the linked duplicate addresses, you can just use inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the class like this:

```
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = "42"

class b(a):
    def printValue(self):
        print(self.value)

b().printValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from other_library import ThatClass

class NewClass(ThatClass):
    def new_method(self):
        # Implement here
        pass
```